# "Many years elapsed before they met"?

Tags: differences

First of all, I would like to let you know I am not a native English speaker.

While looking for some words in a dictionary, I saw this sentence:

"Many years elapsed before they met again."

To me, it sounds like a little bit strange, and "They met again after many years elapsed" looks more natural.

Is there any difference between these two?

or, is it just a matter of style?

Thank you.

Comment: Your cited usage is *slightly* "strange" - but only because it's "dated". See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Many+years+passed+before%2CMany+years+elapsed+before&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMany%20years%20passed%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMany%20years%20elapsed%20before%3B%2Cc0) which clearly shows that we nearly always use ***passed*** rather than ***elapsed*** in such contexts today. This "stylistic" preference has completely reversed from standard usage a century ago.

Comment: It might also sound more natural to you with a slightly different verb tense: *Many years* ***had*** *elapsed before they met again.* Or, to rephrase it completely, *Many years* ***will*** *elapse before we meet again.* In none of these cases does *elapse* need to be the last word in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Many years elapsed before they met again."
>
> "They met again after many years elapsed."

Both are acceptable and mean the same.

Comment: The storytelling effect, though,  is completely different.